# MVC routing mystery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a simple app that was created using MVC4 and Internet Application template.  I excluded the followings and deployed to a IIS7 server.

```
/App_Start/AuthConfig.cs
/Controllers/AccountController.cs
all views under /Views/Account/
AuthConfig.RegisterAuth() in Global.asax.cs
```

When the app starts with `//HostingIIS/MyApp/`, it always routes to `AccountController's login(string returnUrl)` with URL as `//HostingIIS/MyApp/Account/Login?returnUrl=...` with 404 error.

If I modify the URL and remove `/Account/Login?` and hit enter, the app will route to `Home/Index` correctly. This problem doesn't occur on Visual Studio Development Server on my machine.

Does anyone know what might cause the problem? Is it something on the hosting IIS?

Comment: When you call ASP.NET MVC "MVC", a kitten dies.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it's the set in the `redirectUrl` in your forms authentication in the `web.config`.

Presumably you're already authenticated locally?

If you delete all your local cookies do you see the same behaviour locally?